# How to use the current user for proxy with WinSCP

Tags: proxy, winscp

I'm writing a .NET (web) application that uses WinSCP to upload files to an SFTP server. The connection to this server goes through an http proxy.

I already found out how to set proxy information (host, port, user and pass) statically, but I was wondering if there is a way to use information from the `defaultProxy` tag in web.config.

Getting the host and port is trivial, but I can't seem to find a way to tell WinSCP to use the current user/pass (i.e. the one the application pool is using), if `useDefaultCredentials` is set.

The WinSCP GUI does not have an option to use the current user, so my guess is it's not possible. But maybe I'm overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible.

You cannot have WinSCP use the default credentials for proxy.

Neither you can retrieve the current user credentials.
See [Get windows proxy username/password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13334463/850848).